# Error when i tried to append multi dimension list on python

Tags: python, list

I tried to append multi dimension list into an empty list. But somehow it didn't works, the terminal show me this error (TypeError: string indices must be integers). Here is my code :

```
dataUser = []
user = input('Input user : ')
type = input('Type : ')
category = input('Category : ')
message = input('Message : ')
dataUser.append([user[type,category,message] ])
```

Comment: What does `user[type,category,message]` mean to you?

Comment: use dictionary instead.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: rip i cant use  dictionary they told me to do it with list.

Comment: dataUser.append([user[type,category,message] ]) this i the right way to append string variable in list ?

Comment: use `dataUser.append([user,type,category,message])`

Comment: oh maybe i will try this one dataUser.append([user,type,category,message])
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dictionary instead.when you call array like `user[x]` x is index of element inside array, but in dictionary it's one of the keys.

```
dataUser = []
user = {}
username = input('Input user : ')
user_type = input('Type : ')
category = input('Category : ')
message = input('Message : ')
user["name"]=username
user["type"]=user_type
user["category"] = category
user["message"] = message
dataUser.append(user)

print(user)
print(dataUser)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sadly i am not allowed to use dictionary.
I just want to know the error message means.

Comment: if you want to use lists put user beside other information like `dataUser.append([user,type,category,message])`